# Facing issues while Enabling Application Insights on a SOLR App Service

Tags: solr, azure

I have installed Solr as an App Service in Azure by following the below articles.
https://www.iamashishsharma.com/2020/11/install-solr-as-azure-app-service.html

Now I am setting Application Insights for logging by following the below article.
https://andyfitz.me/blog/post/solr-app-service-application-insights#

But after setting up the application insights, Application Insights Causes the `Solr` Application to "`Not Start`".

When I try to see an error on `Solr` side in `httpplatform-sttdout.log` file, its look like below.

```
Access is denied.
Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 29670
INFO  - 2023-01-12 07:07:26.320; org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec; I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:29670: Permission denied: connect
```

What will be the possible error?
Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0):

The **"Access is denied"** and **"Permission denied: connect"** errors you're encountering in the **httpplatform-sttdout.log** file indicate that there might be an issue related to permissions or access rights. Here are some steps to troubleshoot and address this problem:

**1. Check Solr Port Configuration:**

Ensure that the Solr application is configured to run on the correct port **(29670 in your case)**. Verify the Solr configuration files, and make sure that there are no conflicts with other services using the same port.

**2. Verify Application Insights Integration:**

Double-check the steps you followed to integrate Application Insights with Solr. Ensure that you have configured it correctly and that there are no issues with the instrumentation key or other settings.

**3. Review Azure App Service Logs:**

Check the Azure App Service logs for any additional information or error messages. Azure provides logs that might give insights into why the application is not starting.

**4. Review Application Insights Logs:**

Examine the logs in Application Insights for any error messages or exceptions related to Solr. This can be done through the Azure Portal.

**5. Ensure Correct Permissions:**

Verify that the Solr process has the necessary permissions to connect to Application Insights. This includes network permissions to make outbound requests.

**6. Review Azure Role Assignments:**

Ensure that the Azure role assigned to the Solr application has the necessary permissions. This includes permissions to read and send telemetry to Application Insights.

By systematically checking each of these points, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue causing Solr to not start when Application Insights is integrated.